# Editing / customising Cart blocks in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.8

Hi I am trying to move some of the blocks around on the cart page, and have looted in loads of files and cant seem to find what I am looking to edit.

I want to reorganise the 5 blocks that display under the list of what is actually in the cart. 
I have a Template Path Hints so I can see what blocks are there and where they are located, but I am beginning to wonder if this is more complicated than I first thought.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can tydy up this part of the page?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps-

1- find layout file in magento theme `checkout.xml`.

2- Find block name which you want to move.

3- Use insert after/before magento XML tag to move these blocks accordingly.

**Note:** kindly backup your files before editing.